# Align title of Bootstrap selectpicker field to the right

Tags: css, select, bootstrap-4, right-to-left

I've created a `select` field using [Creative Tim's Material Dashboard Pro](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-pro).

I want to align the select field and its option to the right, but so far I managed to align only the options, not its title or the selected option:

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, only the options are aligned to the right, but not the title of the field.

[image]

Even after I choose an option, the title is still aligned to the left and not to the right.

This is the code I'm using to create this `select` field:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" title="Select One" dir="rtl">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

How can I align the title of the `select` field to the right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap-select align only text right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706194/bootstrap-select-align-only-text-right)

Comment: @PrakashKarena No, I have tried doing that already, but the title is still aligned to the left

Comment: can you provide online snippet like codpen so, i can check what  problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to solve it, using HTML tags inside the `title` attribute and by using the `data-content` attribute, like this:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" title="<p style='text-align: right; margin-right: 30px;'>Select One</p>" dir="rtl">
    <option data-content="<p style='text-align: right; margin-right: 30px;'>A</p>" value="a">A</option>
    <option data-content="<p style='text-align: right; margin-right: 30px;'>B</p>" value="b">B</option>
    <option data-content="<p style='text-align: right; margin-right: 30px;'>C</p>" value="c">C</option>
</select>
```