# Bootstrap selectpicker align to right

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-selectpicker

I want to align the selectpicker in Bootstrap to the right. Below is how it looks currently:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qOXV.png)

This is the code:

```
     <div class="input-prepend input-append text-right">
        <select class="selectpicker">
          <option class="text-right">مرة واحدة</option> 
          <option class="text-right">اسبوعي</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

I was able to align the options to the right, but not when they are selected. Any advise?

Comment: I think there are people who tried this thing out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58768164/3202440

Comment: it didn't work for me